# What's the role of "My Info" under Contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I found a generic siri generated Contact card that identified myself in iOS for purposes unknown to me. This appears consistent with the following support page

> iPhone uses your Apple ID to create your contact card, called My Card, but you may need to provide your contact information (such as name and address) to complete it.
>
> https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/add-your-contact-info-iph18b749db1/ios

How exactly are `My Info` and `My Card` related? Is My Info just a subset of things selected from My Card which is a specific vCard in My Contacts that I associate with myself? How do apps and other devices see information from My Info and what precisely is visible from it?

[image: Contacts - My Info]